# Converting from Excel formula to VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

What's the equivalent of the following Excel code in VBA?

```
=MATCH(A1,Ranged_Name,0)
```

where Ranged_Name is a ranged name on the workbook level.

Comment: You may want to read about [worksheet functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.WorksheetFunction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both a worksheet cell and VBA:

```
Sub dural()
    MsgBox Evaluate("Match(A1,Range_Name,0)")
End Sub
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

Based on the Comments, a better alternative:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, v As Variant, wf As WorksheetFunction

    Set r1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    Set r2 = Range("Range_Name")
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

    v = wf.Match(r1, r2, 0)
    MsgBox v
End Sub
```

and to use `Find()`:

```
Sub larud()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, v As Variant

    Set r1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    Set r2 = Range("Range_Name")

    v = r2.Find(What:=r1.Value, After:=r2(1)).Row

    MsgBox v
End Sub
```

Comment: Might be an improvment to use the `Worksheet.Evaluate` method, rather than the `Application` version?  Otherwise, the result will vary according to which sheet is active.

Comment: I used Evaluate("Match('Sheet1'!A1,Range_Name,0)") and that also worked. :)

Comment: @GarryWang  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I surely feel like the student here. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 4):

To add one more:

```
Dim r
With Activesheet
    r = Application.Match(.Range("A1").Value, Range("Ranged_Name"), 0)
End with

If Not IsError(r) Then
    'got a match
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use Range().Find or [Evaluate()](https://analystcave.com/excel-vba-evaluate-tips-and-tricks-to-use-application-evaluate/) your Match, if the sheet is the ActiveSheet.